# How would I generate every possible combination of 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, combinations

So I would have 2 lists, with a random amount of values.
for example:

```
listx = [15513, 813, 984949, 5000], listj = [76815, 75, 8484, 9419419, 418841814, 84848, 84848]
```

How would I generate every possible combination of these lists?
Like:

```
combination = [15513, 75, 9419419]
```

it can take as much values as it wants from both list to use in the combination, I want to check every single combination, like it can take 2 values from the first one and 5 from the other, or all from the first one and 3 from the other.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to include your attempt?

Comment: Look into the itertools (combination, permutation, product, etc.)

Comment: You look up how to do combinations in Python and write your code.  See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  If you have trouble with that code, *then* you might have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I didn't have an attempt since I didn't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

listx = [15513, 813, 984949, 5000]
listj = [76815, 75, 8484, 9419419, 418841814, 84848, 84848]

for i in range(2, len(listx) + len(listj)):
    print(list(combinations(chain(*[listx,listj]), i)))
```